# PHP Login script, session variables or $_GET

Tags: php, session, get

I am creating a login script.

When the user logs in I am at the minute pulling the data from mysql by setting a php session with the users email, then using that to pull an array for everything I need. Would it be better to carry on using a session, or to pull it from the url using $_GET, either is easy to do, just wondered from all angles which is better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session should be used for storing user-specific data, like username. This is protected (the session contents are stored on the server side), while the $_GET can be modified by everyone.

Comment: Ok cool, so as the email is specific to each user, it should be a session?

Comment: General idea: everything that comes from a user _might_ be intentionally or unintentionally dangerous or misformed. That applies not only to `$_GET`, but also to `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE` and so on. So, it is a good idea to fetch everything that possible from _secure_ sources, like your DB. Also, by setting `$_SESSION` variables you are able to retrieve it from any script without need to explicitly pass it via `GET` or `POST` request.